# Почему не ловится исключение

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: исключение]

Изменил имя конфигурационного файла, в конце добавил единичку, но исключение не ловится, почему?

```
#!usr/bin/env python
#coding:utf-8

import configparser
config = confgparser.RawConfigParser()
try:
    config.read('autogen_owen.cfg')
except:
    print ("Отсутсвует конфигурационный файл")
else:
    print (config.get('system', 'version'))
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, перенесите код и содержимое исключение с картинки прямо в вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас Exception происходит в блоке else, поэтому NoSectionError и не ловится.

Если вы хотите проверить существование конфигурационного файла, лучше вызывать метод os.path.exists или проверять результат метода config.read на пустой список. Так как метод config.read игнорирует отсутствие файла и вместо исключение возвращает пустой список.

Answer (score 1):

Метод read не выбрасывает исключений. В документации написано "If a file named in filenames cannot be opened, that file will be ignored." Остаётся либо проверять наличие файла с помощью `os.path.exists()`, либо проверять `config.has_section('system')`.

Answer (score 1):

Отловить любую ошибку можно следующим образом:

```
 except NameOfYourError as e:
        print(e)
        make_something_with_this()
```

главное вписать этот блок в то место куда нужно, и не перепутаться с иерархией.